# How to exclude a keyword or make a blacklist for some keywords when retweeting using tweepy

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy

I know how to make a bot that retweets the tweets containing certain tag or keywords:

```
tag = 'My_keyword'
# Looping through tweets
for tweet in tweepy.Cursor(api.search, q=tag,
).items():
    try:
        print('\nTweet by: @' + tweet.user.screen_name)
        # Retweet tweets as they are found
        tweet.retweet()
        print('Retweeted the tweet')
        sleep(randint(1,2))            

    except tweepy.TweepError as e:
        print(e.reason)

    except StopIteration:
        break
```

But how can I make a blacklist of keywords that checks if it is in the tweet skip the tweet and go to the next one... ?

Answer (score 0):

Do check the [documentation](http://docs.tweepy.org/en/v3.5.0/getting_started.html) for a more detailed guide. You can get the tweets text with `tweet.full_text`, then using string comparison, you can check whether a certain word is in the tweet's text.

```
if 'bad_word' in tweet.full_text:
    continue
```

If you have a list of words, you can do something like

```
If any([bw in tweet.full_text for bw in bad_word_list]):
```

Comment: Exception has occurred: AttributeError
'Status' object has no attribute 'full_text'

Comment: Might be .text then

Comment: I tried `tweet.text` but it runs without any error but it doesn't work , still retweets the excluded keyword